# How to organize SQL script files & folders

Tags: sql, oracle, naming, file-organization

We have an Oracle 10g database (a huge one) in our company, and I provide employees with data upon their requests. My problem is, I save almost every SQL query I wrote, and now my list has grown too long. I want to organize and rename these .sql files so that I can find the one I want easily. At the moment, I'm using some folders named as `Sales Dept, Field Team, Planning Dept, Special` etc. and under those folders there are .sql files like

```
Delivery_sales_1, Delivery_sales_2, ...
Sent_sold_lostsales_endpoints, ...
Sales_provinces_period, Returnrates_regions_bymonths, ...
Jack_1, Steve_1, Steve_2, ...
```

I try to name the files regarding their content but this makes file names longer and does not completely meet my needs. Sometimes someone comes and demands a special report, and I give the file his name, but this is also not so good. I know duplicates or very similar files are growing in time but I don't have control over them.

Can you show me the right direction to rename all these files and folders and organize my queries for easy and better control? TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Folders are a lousy way to catalog large numbers of files such that you can find things later.  I have known colleagues to obsessively create hundreds of folders and subfolders in Outlook to categorise every piece of mail that comes in; they then spend several minutes opening folder after folder trying to remember where they put things.  Me, I just keep everything in the Inbox and then use Google Desktop Search to find them - much quicker!  Similarly, I tend to keep all my ad hoc SQL scripts in a single folder c:\sql and then use Google Desktop Search to find those.

Alternatively, perhaps you could build a simple database to keep them in, with a table like:

```
create table sql_scripts
  ( id integer primary key -- populated by a trigger
  , sql clob
  , date_created date default sysdate
  , who_for varchar2(30)
  , title varchar2(100)
  , keywords varchar2(100)
  );
```

Then you could insert, for example:

```
insert into sql_scripts
  ( sql
  , who_for varchar2(30)
  , title varchar2(100)
  , keywords varchar2(100)
  ) values
  ( 'select ename from emp where deptno=10'
  , 'Steve Jones'
  , 'List of employees in department 10'
  , 'hr,emp,dept10'
  );
```

You can then later search this in various ways e.g.

```
select * from sql_scripts
where upper(who_for) like 'STEVE%'
and upper(sql) like '%DEPTNO%'
and date_created > sysdate-365;
```